# If dates match get data

Tags: date, import, google-sheets, match

I have two separate GoogleSheets documents. One with a list of dates and names (let's call this Doc1), the other with a list of names and contact numbers (we'll call this Doc2). Here's what I'm trying to do:

In Doc2. Pull the name from Doc1 corresponding with today's date. Then pull the contact number from Doc2 and put it next to the name.

Sounds simple enough, but I've tried to do this with vlookup to no avail, and was wondering if someone here could point me in the right direction?

For clarification, Doc1 looks something like:

```
| Day           | Date          | Team 1 | Team 2 | Team 3 |
|---------------|---------------|--------|--------|--------|
|Monday         | 2 Mar 2015    |Bob     |Adam    |Dave    |
|Tuesday        | 3 Mar 2015    |John    |James   |Mike    |
|Wednesday      | 4 Mar 2015    |Philip  |Dan     |John    |
```

Doc2 looks something like:

```
| Team          | Todays Date   | Name   | Contact No |
|---------------|---------------|--------|------------|
|Team 1         | 03/03/2015    |        |            |
|Team 2         | 03/03/2015    |        |            |
|Team 3         | 03/03/2015    |        |            |
```

The contact numbers are listed on other pages in Doc2, next to the names.
So, what I'm trying to figure out is how in Doc2, to match today's date against the row with corresponding date in Doc1 and pull the name from Doc1 into Doc2, then pull the number from Doc2 that corresponds with the name that has now been pulled.

**EDIT**

This is what the sheet looks like, accurately. The column letters are listed exactly as they are on the sheet I am working with: E,H,K,N,Q,T,W,Z,AC,AF,AI,AL,AO,AR being used as dividers. Awkward, I know. But someone else made the original sheet and I can't edit it.

pnuts script worked, and returned the first name Bob, but for the team underneath it returned the Initials in the Hit category (in the example, BB). And for every entry after that (save the very next one, which returned blank) it returns REF# with the error: "Function INDEX parameter 3 value is 5. Valid values are between 0 and 4 inclusive." with the value of 5 goign all the way upto 15. (There are 14 teams, plus the title, which I guess makes it upto 15)

```
  A           B               C        D    E F        G    H I        J  
| Day       | Date          | Team 1 | Hit  | Team 2 | Hit  | Team 3 | Hit  |
|-----------|---------------|--------|------|--------|------|--------|------|
|Monday     | 2 Mar 2015    |Bob     | BB   |Adam    | AD   |Dave    | DV   |
|Tuesday    | 3 Mar 2015    |John    | JN   |James   | JM   |Mike    | MK   |
|Wednesday  | 4 Mar 2015    |Philip  | PH   |Dan     | DN   |John    | JN   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layouts and different documents don't help but perhaps would get you started, assuming `Day` is in sheet `S1` of `Doc1` and `Team` in `A1` of `Doc2`, please try in `C1` and copy down to suit (UNTESTED):

```
=transpose(index(importrange("<key>","S1!b1:e"),index(match(B2,importrange("<key>","S1!b2:b"),0)+1),row()))
```

You would have to provide the appropriate `key` value and authorise the link.

Comment: Thanks for yoru help pnuts! It works, sorta. It worked for the first person on the sheet it was pulling the names from. But the sheet is laid out in an obscure way. I will edit my post above to give a bit better of an idea, as I cant share the sheet due to sensitive info.

Comment: Through some odd bastardisation of this, I managed to get it working. Just using "Rota!b1:c" for the 1st person, "Rota!d1:f" for the 2nd, "Rota!f1:i" for the 3rd and so on. Climbing in increments of 2 for the 1st letter, and 3 for the 2nd letter (to give an idea, my final formula in the list looks like: `=transpose(index(importrange("KEY,"Rota!ab1:aq"),index(match(B15,importrange("KEY","Rota!b2:b"),0)+1),row()))`

Comment: Ok. One sleight hiccup. This is working, and doing its job just fine, however due to not being able to edit the original docs, I've hot a wall. If a person is named, for example. Bob Davis on Doc1, and Doc2 has him as Bob T Davis, it won't match due to the names being different. Doc2 also pulls info from another sheet, so I can't edit it to make it match. Is there any way to use anything like concatenate along side this formula?

Comment: Im sorta slowly working around it. I was thinking, I could use IF and REGEXREPLACE? But Im not sure how to attach it together. I currently have an IF statement at the start (as it checks a time/date). I currently have: `=IF(NOW()>=TODAY()+TIME(9,0,0),transpose(index(importrange("key","Rota!i1:o"),index(match(B3,importrange("key","Rota!b2:b"),0)+1),row())),transpose(index(importrange("key","Rota!i1:o"),index(match(Today()-1,importrange("key","Rota!b2:b"),0)+1),row())))` and somehow want to involve; `IF(C7="Eddie",REGEXREPLACE(C7, "Eddie", "Edward"),))`. I've tried with `AND` but made a mess :/